# Perform OCR on images in Google Documents

Tags: google-docs, google-drive-api

I want to use Google's OCR capability to extract words from images in a document I have. I know I can pull each image out and then reupload them to pull out the text or turn it into a PDF and then upload it but I'd like to not go through those extra steps if possible.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't perform OCR on an image after it's uploaded because OCR creates a Google Doc instead of an image file type. Instead, use [files.copy](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/copy) to create a new copy of the file and set ocr to True. The newly created copy of the file will have OCR performed. Using files copy does not pull the file data down over the wire so bandwidth usage is minimal.

Comment: @JayLee How should I get the result back?! There are a lot of examples using INSERT method but not COPY or CREATE. :(